# Mascara monetário com jquery.inputmask

Tags: jquery, mask

Como faço para criar uma mascara par um valor monetário?

Estou usando esse:

```
$(".ValoresItens").inputmask('R$ 999.999.999,99', { numericInput: true});
```

ficou assim: R$ ____.____._25,00

Mas eu não gostei desses underline, queria que fosse dinâmico.

Comment: vc quer remover os `_` isso? coloca o link do plugin que está usando. Se for o que eu estou pensando vc pode trocar os `_` por espaços.

Comment: Só trocar os espaços em branco não seria o suficiente, pois ficaria uma espaço entre o valor e o "R$", estou usando: jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2

Comment: E trocar por zero?

Comment: Pó de ser, mas acho mais elegante não ter nada, fica feio para o usuário a representar um valor assim R$000.000.010,00

Comment: O tratamento do evento submit, se faz necessário quando a opção está configurada como digits:0, com valores inteiros, sem a casa decimal, apesar de redundante, somente fiz funcionar assim.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Se estiver usando o plugin [jquery.inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask), definir a mascara dinâmica adicionado as opções de separador de milhar e decimais, para remover os underlines troque o placholder por zero.

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- não esqueça de adicionar os js do jquery e do pluging !-->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#money").inputmask('decimal', {
                'alias': 'numeric',
                'groupSeparator': ',',
                'autoGroup': true,
                'digits': 2,
                'radixPoint': ".",
                'digitsOptional': false,
                'allowMinus': false,
                'prefix': 'R$ ',
                'placeholder': ''
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <form>
      <input type="text" id="money" /><br>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Esse funcionou bem, só ficou estranho o esquema do decimal, mas tá muito bom.

Comment: @GabrielSantosReis o placheholder vc deixou em branco ou colocou zero?

Comment: @rray, estou enfrentando problemas com valores arredondados, por ex: `R$ 2.000,00`. Com essa configuração o plugin está colocando a virgula no lugar do ponto. Com valores não arredondados está ok, por ex: `R$ 2.500,55`

Comment: @ThiagoPereira, acho melhor criar uma nova pergunta, lembre de colocar um exemplo testavel assim mais pessoas podem resolver o problema :)

Comment: @rray deixei em branco mesmo.

Comment: Funciona so para inputs?  Preciso de um desse para funcionar em uma tag tipo td  é póssivel?

Answer (score 13):

Olá, companheiro.
No seu caso eu recomendaria o uso do plugin [Jquery Maskmoney](https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney), Esse pluginzinho já vem no jeito para formatar campos para dinheiro de acordo com suas necessidades, além de algumas opções bem legais. Você pode acessar a última versão desse plugin minificada [clicando aqui](https://cdn.rawgit.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney/master/dist/jquery.maskMoney.min.js)

Para formatar um campo com esse plugin de acordo com o que está pedindo, use isso:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $(".ValoresItens").maskMoney({
         prefix: "R$:",
         decimal: ",",
         thousands: "."
     });
});
```

Dessa maneira, o seu campo terá o prefixo R$: (citado na opção *prefix*), os decimais serão separados por uma vírgula (opção *decimal*), e os milhares serão separados por um ponto (opção *thousands*).

Comment: Rapaz, se tivesse uma versão desse plugin sem JQuery seria formidável.

Answer (score 6):

Com o [jQuery Mask Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) basta utilizar o seguinte:

```
  $('.money').mask('#.##0,00', {reverse: true});
```

Acredito que este plugin seja melhor que o jquery.inputmask

Comment: uso esse plugin não só pra dinheiro, como pra peso, altura, etc, é muito bom!

Comment: Excelente mesmo. Acho que o que eu mais uso é pra telefone e cpf

Answer (score 3):

Acabei de utilizar esta configuração e deu certo, esta configuração é para R$:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- não esqueça de adicionar os js do jquery e do pluging !-->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#money").inputmask( 'currency',{"autoUnmask": true,
            radixPoint:",",
            groupSeparator: ".",
            allowMinus: false,
            prefix: 'R$ ',            
            digits: 2,
            digitsOptional: false,
            rightAlign: true,
            unmaskAsNumber: true
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <form>
      <input type="text" id="money" /><br>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     // prepara o input com a mascara
     jQuery(function ($) {
        $("#money").inputmask( 'currency',{"autoUnmask": true,
                    radixPoint:",",
                    groupSeparator: ".",
                    allowMinus: false,
                    prefix: 'R$ ',            
                    digits: 0,
                    digitsOptional: false,
                    rightAlign: true,
                    unmaskAsNumber: true,
                    removeMaskOnSubmit: true
        });
     });

    // retira a mascara do campo
    $(document).on("submit", function () {
        $("#money").inputmask('unmaskedvalue');
    });
```

Veja a minha solução para a questão, obrigado!!

Comment: No [pt.so] você deve publicar em português. Se for editar para traduzir, aproveite para adicionar uma descrição de como resolveu e, principalmente, como a sua solução é diferente das outras já presentes no tópico.

Comment: Por que precisa tratar o evento `submit` para remover a máscara se você está utilizando a opção `removeMaskOnSubmit: true`?